# DateTime issue in database

Tags: java, sql, datetime

I am assigning value to a variable like

```
chkTime= new DateTime()
```

where chkTime is of DateTime data type.

And then I save this variable in my db. But there is difference in timezone. And I am getting 5 hours' difference. I went through internet stuff and found that it may be GMT stuff difference but I specified Zone as well and still I am in the same pool.

What am I missing ?

I want the dataTime to be saved according to the currentTime zone where application is running

Comment: The question is a bit vague as it is difficult to understand if the issue is with  instantiation of DateTime or the inserting into the database. Could you please provide this; Print chkTime and share the output. `System.out.println(chkTime);` Also share what MySQL column type you are trying to insert it into.

Comment: 2017-01-03T12:55:23.863+05:00
this is what I get when I print new DateTime()
But on saving in database I see
2017-01-03 07:55:23.863
and I expect 2017-01-03 12:55:23.863

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag. I am using SQL and datatype for that column is dateTime

Comment: Alright, the  issue is obviously with inserting into the MySQL db. What column type are you inserting into? `DATE`. `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: DATETIME is the data type

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the issue is occurring on inserting into the SQL database. The `DATETIME` format of the column does not provide time zone support for globally deployed applications.

Use `DATETIMEOFFSET` to add time zone awareness.

```
ALTER TABLE <schemaName>.<tableName>
ALTER COLUMN <columnName> DateTimeOffset [NULL|NOT NULL]
```

Comment: Still the same exact thing? Where is the database server located? Is it on your local machine on in a remote location? Can you check the timezone of the location on the database server?

Comment: I changed my datatype to timestamp and it started working as expected.
Couldn't figure out what the issue was..
Any ways, thanks for your time :)